# Java: Sum of values inside a Collection of DTO

Tags: java, java-8, sum, java-stream

Calculate the sum of amountField in MyDTO, Java 8

```
private Double getSum(List<MyDTO> myDTOList) {
    return myDTOList.stream().map(MyDTO::getAmount).reduce(0d, Double::sum);
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Stream.mapToDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToDouble(java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction)) to convert it into a `DoubleStream` and then use [`DoubleStream.sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#sum()):

```
return myDTOList.stream().mapToDouble(MyDTO::getAmount).sum();
```

To mention, the above shall work for `amount` being of `integer` type as well, while the code shared by you and this shall still work fine if the type of amount is already `double`.

---

Or as pointed out in comments by you, if your DTO object can be null, you can filter out those values using:

```
return myDTOList.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).mapToDouble(MyDTO::getAmount).sum();
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, just an additional null check.
return myDTOList.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).mapToDouble(MyDTO::getAmount).sum();

Comment: @vinit yes that would be helpful id your objects could possibly be null.